# Understanding preprocessor directives in this case?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define swap(a,b,c)(int t;t=a;a=b;b=t;);
void main()
{
    int x=10,y=20;
    swap (x,y,int);
    printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
}
```

What is the output and why?

Comment: Where do use `c` in your macro?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and it's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 6):

Better to re-write your macro like this:

```
#define swap(a, b, type) \
        do { \
                type t = a; \
                a = b; \
                b = t; \
        } while (0)
```

Comment: Not "better," _necessary_. OP's macro should not compile.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the *usage* and on the fact that `c` is not used in the macro, it looks like there's a typo in the macro.  Instead of using `int`, it should say `c`:

```
#define swap(a,b,c)(c t;t=a;a=b;b=t;);
```

In fact, while this "fix" will give you the general idea of the macro, it won't compile.  Please see [Peyman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930391/understanding-preprocessor-directives-in-this-case/4930440#4930440) which tells you how to write it correctly.

Basically, it looks like a way to swap two variables `a`,`b` of the type `c`.

In your case the output would be:

```
20 10
```

The way this swapping algorithm works is simple.  Basically, you want to copy `a` into `b` and `b` into `a`.  However, if you just copy `b` into `a`, you'll lose `a`, and you'll be stuck with two copies of `b`.

Instead of just copying `b` into `a`, you first save a copy of `a` into a *temporary variable* called `t`, then copy `b` into `a`, then copy `t` (which holds the original value of `a`) into `b`.  When you're done, you can forget about `t`.

Comment: You can't put statements in parentheses or declare variables in expressions. The macro needs a bit more work.

Comment: @Chris: of course, you're absolutely right.  I'll put a reference to your answer in mine.  While your answer explains how to make it compile, mine gives a little bit more insight into how it works.

Comment: @Chris: obviously, I mean Peyman's, not yours, since you didn't answer the question.